# Javascript confirm alert with dynamic text executed on server side VB.NET while cancel button still working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm using VB.NET web form. I've tried every variation I could find online, but none seem to fit my needs. I need a javascript confirm function that will contain dynamic text to execute from server side upon pressing a button. I need the routine to actually cancel when users press cancel. When they press cancel, the code should no longer execute and the page should stay the same. Right now, it doesn't matter if they press OK or Cancel, it still executes the code. This seems to be because it can't find the Request.Form value that it executes the IF/THEN from, so it just always executes the "ELSE" portion. If they press Cancel, the Label text should change with "You have pressed cancel."

This is what I have so far:

---

CLIENT SIDE:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        first page<br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"   />
    </asp:Panel>

</div>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
    confirmation page<br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>
```

---

SERVER SIDE:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As    System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Panel1.Visible = True
        Panel2.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click



    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
    sb.Append("function Confirm() {")
    sb.Append("var confirm_value = document.createElement('INPUT');")
    sb.Append("confirm_value.type = 'hidden';")
    sb.Append("confirm_value.name = 'confirm_value';")
    sb.Append("if (confirm('You are about to purchase " & DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text & " positions.')) {")
    sb.Append("confirm_value.value = 'Yes';")
    sb.Append(" } else {")
    sb.Append(" confirm_value.value = 'No';")
    sb.Append("}")
    sb.Append("document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);")
    sb.Append("}")
    sb.Append("</script>")

    Response.Write(sb)

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Page.GetType, "Script", "Confirm();", True)


    Dim confirmValue As String = Request.Form("confirm_value")
    If confirmValue = "Yes" Then
        'do nothing
        Label1.Text = "You have pressed cancel."
    Else

        Panel1.Visible = False
        Panel2.Visible = True

        Label1.Text = "You are about to purchase " & DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text & " positions."
    End If




End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you want this code.
my english skill is low.
I may have a misunderstanding about your question.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click



    Dim confirmValue As String = Request.Form("confirm_value")
    If confirmValue = "Yes" Then
        'do nothing
        Label1.Text = "You have pressed cancel."
    Else If confirmValue = "No" Then

        Panel1.Visible = False
        Panel2.Visible = True

        Label1.Text = "You are about to purchase " & DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text & " positions."
    Else


    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
    sb.Append("function Confirm() {")
    sb.Append("var confirm_value = document.createElement('INPUT');")
    sb.Append("confirm_value.type = 'hidden';")
    sb.Append("confirm_value.name = 'confirm_value';")
    sb.Append("if (confirm('You are about to purchase " & DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text & " positions.')) {")
    sb.Append("confirm_value.value = 'Yes';")
    sb.Append(" } else {")
    sb.Append(" confirm_value.value = 'No';")
    sb.Append("}")
    sb.Append("document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);")
    sb.Append("document.getElementById(" + Button1.ClientID + ").click()");
    sb.Append("}")
    sb.Append("</script>")

    Response.Write(sb)

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Page.GetType, "Script", "Confirm();", True)

    End If



End Sub
```

-- add --

if you can use Static id

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

to

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

and

```
sb.Append("document.getElementById(" + Button1.ClientID + ").click()");
```

to

```
sb.Append("document.getElementById('Button1').click()")
```

i think need change your if statement.

```
Dim confirmValue As String = Request.Form("confirm_value")
If confirmValue = "Yes" Then ******
    'do nothing
    Label1.Text = "You have pressed cancel."
Else If confirmValue = "No" Then ******

    Panel1.Visible = False
    Panel2.Visible = True

    Label1.Text = "You are about to purchase " & DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text & " positions."
```

to

```
Dim confirmValue As String = Request.Form("confirm_value")
If confirmValue = "No" Then ******
    'do nothing
    Label1.Text = "You have pressed cancel."
Else If confirmValue = "Yes" Then ******

    Panel1.Visible = False
    Panel2.Visible = True

    Label1.Text = "You are about to purchase " & DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text & " positions."
```

Comment: Sorry, that did not work. I copied your exact code. When button was pressed, then "Cancel" was selected, it did not display the "You have pressed cancel" message.

Comment: if you can use Static id         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"   ClientIDMode="Static"/> and sb.Append("document.getElementById('Button1').click()");

Comment: Ok, tried that and still not getting expected results.

Comment: i can see your current code? this code work in my computer. T.T

Comment: I applied your updates and then switched the Yes/No answers and it almost works. Pressing "OK" will execute the code. Pressing "Cancel" seems to cancel the code. BUT, pressing Cancel does not display the "You have pressed cancel" text.

Comment: I think that's the problem with your if statement.
you can change If confirmValue = "Yes" <=> If confirmValue = "No"

Comment: but i think this code is not good.
why you make javascript code from server side?

Comment: I am making javascript code from server side so that I could do an alert box that has a dynamic number in the alert message (the number selected from dropdownbox) and also so that I can perform different server functions based on if they press OK or cancel.

Comment: I still can't get the cancel message to display if they press cancel. Does the cancel message display on your code?

Comment: I'm abandoning this approach. It's just too messy. Thanks for your help. You did provide the exact code to do what I needed to do.